# How to update minicart view using AJAX?

Tags: magento2, cart, ajax, mini-cart, view

Is there any way to update the mini cart view?

Now I'm using:

```
      require([
            'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
        ], function (customerData) {

            alert("hola");
            var sections = ['cart'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
        });
```

But it only refreshes the view by updating the page.

I'm looking for ways to make the changes reflect without having to reload the page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try the below code.

```
require([
           'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
        ], function (customerData) {
            var sections = ['cart'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        });
```

Comment: when i recharge the page show "You added Pantalon vaquero to your shopping cart." could remove the message for no show?

Comment: NOt working for me.I am removing an item from minicart it is not removing checkout button.

Comment: Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalidate' of undefined

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue, used single line in ajax success to update mini cart.

```
require('Magento_Customer/js/customer-data').reload();
```

Full Ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
        $('#ck-quick-qosubmit').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    url:"/quickadd/quick",
                    method:"POST",

                    data:{
                       sku: $('#ck-quick-sku').val(),
                       qty: $('#ck-quick-qty').val(),
                    },
                    success:function(response) {
                        $('#ck-quickbuy-response').html(response);
                        require('Magento_Customer/js/customer-data').reload();
                   },
                   error:function(){
                     console.log('error');
                   }

              });

        }); 
    });     

</script>
```

Hope this will help someone in future :)

Answer (score 2):

The right way of doing this (usually it's enough) is adding your action to section.xml.
See example in Magento_Checkout:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
<action name="checkout/cart/add">
    <section name="cart"/>
</action>
```

Actually after that magento will do the same as @suresh-chikani showed on *ajaxComplete* event