# Magento 2 : How to reload minicart from Plugin?

Tags: plugin, magento2.2.6, mini-cart

I've written plugin for `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart::Delete`

Plugin works great and removed my desirable product from cart.

As much as I know Minicart is render with local storage. So that we have to update it with `sections.xml`.

But I looked into it and found that `sections.xml` only contains actions.

**So How can I reload minicart whenever I use plugin ?**

**UPDATE**

Thing is like I want to remove one specific product when any changes made to the cart Like, Update qty, Remove existing item from cart etc.

If any of above changes occur than let's say I've **product ID-5** that product needs to be remove from automatically.

**Example:**

I've 4 products in cart including my free product(has price USD 0)

```
Item Name  -   Qty    
Product-1  -   1
Product-2  -   2
Product-3  -   1
Product-4  -   1
(Free product)
```

If any changes to qty happens to products expect free product than free product needs to be removed and qty update will be there for that product.

**PS: I've disabled qty update for free product.**

**`What I've tried.`**

```
public function beforeExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Delete $subject
    )
    {
        $items = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $product = $this->product->load($item->getProductId());
            if($product->getSku() == $this->helperData->getGeneralConfig('free_product')){ // get product sku 
                $this->cart->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();

                $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
            }
         }

        $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->url->getUrl('checkout/cart/');
        $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
        die();

    }
```

Above is working but minicart isn't update. along with side bar total on cart page.

> If you have any other solution rather than plugin than add your
>   solution too.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: not sure but this might be helpful to you - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178125/magento2-update-minicart-view-using-ajax/178226

Comment: No Rahul this is different case.

Comment: I am facing this same problem.

Comment: since minicart is private content, it needs to be invalidated and requested again using javascript to be re-rendered correctly on the frontend, sections.xml is a system to do that, but it can be triggered manually too, are you interested in such an answer? asking because of the "I'm stuck with Plugin only" sentence.

Comment: @igrossiter, Well I have idea about sections.xml but the thing I wanted to achieve i think possible with plugin only. So i added 'i'm stuck with plugin only', but I've added whole thing that needs to be achieve If you have solution for this without plugin.Than I'm glad to look into this.

Comment: Did you call any request to remove Product-5 automaticaly ??

Comment: @HoangHieu, There is no Product-5 . You can consider Product-4 as free product and its already in cart.
And to answer your question there is no any special(hidden) request to add free product to cart. user will get a pop up at cart page when he is eligible for that.
So after that if any changes occur than free needs to be remove.

Comment: That means Product-5 will be removed when product 4 has been removed from cart?. Your popup is an Iframe, isn't it?. If an iframe you need reload the web page after close popup.

Comment: @HoangHieu, Yes product-5 will be removed when any changes occur to cart, Not only changes to product-4 (I mean any product). Regarding pop-up I made it custom with normal jQuery popup it will apprear only when cart is greater than 50. and pop-up updating mini cart via ajax so no need to reaload web page. Actually I've weltpixel quick view enable So i've modified it to show pop-up to cart page contains with free product.

Comment: *pop-up updating mini cart via ajax so no need to reaload web page.* This is your problem when you closed popup and your mini card didn't update. what why I need you reload your webpage (This easily to doing), or you can try reload customerSections['cart'] to reload your minicard after ajax completed.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should use **checkout_cart_save_before** to add/remove your free product whenever cart is saved. You can see my solution here:

> 1. app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_save_before">
        <observer name="training_test_checkout" instance="YourVendor\YourModule\Observer\ValidateFreeProduct"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> 2. app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Observer/ValidateFreeProduct.php

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class ValidateFreeProduct implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        /** @var Cart $cart */
        $cart = $event->getCart();
        if (!$cart instanceof Cart) {
            return;
        }
        $yourCondition = false;
        if (!$yourCondition) {
            $sku = 'your_free_product_sku';
            foreach ($cart->getItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == $sku) {
                    $cart->removeItem($item->getItemId());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By using this event, when you delete/update your cart, the mini cart will be updated automatically

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your effort  Lee but same situation mini cart counter is there no changes there.

Comment: I tested it's working for me on Magento 2.1.10. Did you try to run php bin/magento clean:cache ?

Comment: Looks like I can't add my free product to cart due to observer is preventing it. Actually Free product is add to cart by user himself. When quote is more than 50 USD than he will get a pop up with free product and from there he can add free product to cart.  So if I use your answer than free product can't be added to cart.

Comment: $yourCondition = false; ==> You should change this to your condition, something like $cartTotal>50 or any condition that you need to validate. I think you are a developer so you should know how to make my solution so that it fits you

Comment: What about minicart ?

Comment: I tested and it worked fine for me. Minicart was updated correctly. Do you need me to record a video? I think a junior developer can follow my steps and see how it is fixed

Comment: see the recording here https://vimeo.com/309106096