# Fully truncate cart on visiting a specific URL

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, mini-cart, magento2.4

I'm trying to fully truncate the cart.

I've override `getAllVisibleItems` in the checkout `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` Model
But I still can visit the cart page and see the empty table of it, and the product also still showing up in the mini-cart

Here is my code

```php
private function truncateUserQuote()
{
   $this->removeAllItems()->save();
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $cs = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
   $cs->getQuote()->removeAllItems()->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sorry to call such attention to this question but there's a **TON** wrong here. Hopefully, you will take some lessons away from this answer.

- **Don't** use the Object Manager in your code
- **Don't** get the quote from the session. But IF you insist, you should probably use `$objectManager->get('class name')` not `$objectManager->create('class name')`. Get ensures that you get a shared instance of the class. Create instantiates a new instance of the class.
- **Don't** override getAllVisibleItems - not sure what your purpose is for that but you WILL make trouble for yourself. Plugins are immediately available for your use and are a MUCH better choice. Also, getAllVisible items doesnt account for the child products if the customer has grouped, bundle, or configurable products. It really only accounts for the visible line items.
- **DO** get used to looking at the Interfaces and using the methods contained in the interfaces only. Interfaces are basically a set of promises to provide the functions you are using. Referencing functions from concrete PHP classes will render your functionality broken during some future upgrade.

Here is a working example. We don't reference the session or object manager and we use only methods available according to the service contract. Work this into your code and test it out.

```
<?php

class CartTest
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $repository;

    /**
     * CartTest constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface $repository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface $repository
    ) {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $cartId
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function emptyCart($cartId)
    {
        /**
         * gets all items belonging to the cart
         */
        $items = $this->repository->getList($cartId);
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $this->repository->deleteById($cartId, $item->getItemId());
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your amazing answer, I was trying to find something clear like this but I didn't found, now this code empties the cart, but I still can see the items in the mini-cart, any way to solve this?

Comment: Hi @AboElnouR the minicart in the native Magento frontend loads vis ajax. This answer will provide some guidance on how to invalidate the content so that it reloads. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178125/how-to-update-minicart-view-using-ajax

Comment: If this answer solves the original problem I would appreciate if you accept. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, I really thank you for this great answer, it helped me so much, I can't thank you more.