# Reload page after removing item from Mini cart in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, cart-items, remove

Is there any way to reload the page completely, when we remove an item from mini cart.
https://prnt.sc/11i1x2g
After clicking on ok , i want to reload the page.

Comment: This solution may be useful to you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/178226/7863

Comment: No it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `_ajax` function of

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js

in your custom theme and add code to reload page after removing item from minicart as below

```
.done(function (response) {
    var msg;

    if (response.success) {
        callback.call(this, elem, response);
        
        window.location.reload(true);// CODE ADDED TO RELOAD PAGE AFTER REMOVING ITEM FROM MINICART SUCCESSFULLY
    
    } else {
        msg = response['error_message'];

        if (msg) {
            alert({
                content: msg
            });
        }
    }
})
```