# Get Mini Cart Update Cart Button Event

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, mini-cart

I want to obtain the event during which this Mini cart update cart button is clicked

[image]

I want to observe when and how many the amount of it being clicked

I try to put below code inside app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/myproject/Magento_Catalog/templates/gtm_body.phtml

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button.update-cart-item').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Clicked");
        })
    })

})
```

but it does not seems to work,

If I try putting directly into console in chrome browser it is working

Not sure how do I obtain this click event. Anyone can help give suggestions?

Any help is kindly appreciated, attached below is the inspect element tab view

[image]

Comment: do update click event is download after and minicart update button is add by knockout js, you try to call this type. $(document).on('click', 'button.update-cart-item', function(e){e.preventDefault();alert("Clicked");})

Comment: have tried, not working

Comment: where is the knockout js that trigger this minicart sidebar open

Comment: file knockout js Magento_Customer/js/customer-data
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178125/how-to-update-minicart-view-using-ajax